# Why are fitted.values not part the R object returned from arima?

Tags: r, time-series, arima

Starting out with arima models in R, I do not understand why fitted.values (of an AR(2) process for example) are not part of the output like they are in regressions. Did I miss them when running `str(result)` or did I get something completely wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `fitted()` function from the `forecast` package. Since arima object saves residuals it is easy to compute fitted values from it.

Comment: okay so you mean like: `fitted(arima(somets,c(2,0,0))`respectively `somets-arimaresult$residuals` . I just wondered WHY this is not part of the output – is it somehow not a good idea to look at these?

Comment: The fitted values from an ARIMA object are one-step forecasts. They are not very interesting and you don't usually need to look at them. The residuals, on the other hand, are useful for checking model assumptions and to see whether the information in the data has been adequately captured in the fitted model.

Comment: @Rob @ran2, I agree with Rob's comment!

Comment: gracias...........!